# Crop android image

Tags: android

I am using compile `com.github.jdamcd:android-crop:1.0.1` library for image cropping.

The `URI` returned after crop is `file:///data/user/0/package_name/cache/cropped`.

With this `URI`,correct image is loaded but when I pass this `URI` in another activity via intent, image loaded is not the complete image instead only a part of it.

How to get the complete image?

Answer (score 0):

> image loaded is not the complete image instead only a part of it.

A third-party app has no rights to this file. It is on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for your app, specifically in a `cropped` subdirectory of the location identified by `getCacheDir()`.

> How to get the complete image?

[Use a `FileProvider` to serve the content](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html), using a `content` `Uri` from `FileProvider` for providing access to that content to another app.